# Dúvida ao pegar valor da Map

Tags: java

Olá. Quando eu imprimo os valores e as chave da `Map`, ele vem de baixo pra cima. Queria saber como faço para pegar de cima para baixo.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class ClassDebug {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("Alemanha", 7);
        map.put("Brasil ", 1);
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }
           // Imprime: Brasil
           // Imprime: Alemanha

         // Eu quero que imprima:

        // Alemanha e Brasil :V
    }
}
```

Comment: E enquanto você lia essa pergunta, mais um gol da Alemanha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `HashMap` não oferece nenhuma garantia quanto a ordem dos elementos. Os elementos de lá podem acabar sendo retirados em qualquer ordem.

Entretanto, se você usar um `LinkedHashMap` ao invés de um `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Isso vai fazer eles serem ordenados pela ordem de inserção.

Uma outra forma é fazer eles serem ordenados alfabeticamente. Use o `TreeMap` neste caso:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Você pode personalizar a ordem dos elementos também usando o [construtor de `TreeMap` que recebe um `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou certinho aqui.